# Not able to mount shared drive on server A to server B

Tags: nfs

I am not able to mount a drive that is located on server A to server B. I have followed [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Share-Files-Between-Linux-Computers-Using-NFS) document step by step just replacing portmap to rpcbind as the system installed rpcbind instead of portmap. I am getting the below exception when I try to mount the file system.

**mount.nfs connection timed out**

My servers are located on Microsoft Azure. I tried pinging from client(server B) to server A but I was not able to. I believe it is a port issue but how to rectify that I am not able to get it.

Please let me know what i need to check to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check telneting to the port on the Azure server, if that fails you might have to modify the Azure servers security group and add a rule that allows ingress to
Port 111 (TCP and UDP) and 2049 (TCP and UDP) for the NFS server, and egress rules for the client. if they are on the same subnet then something else is wrong.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

Comment: also check local firewalls such as firewalld or iptables

Comment: Thanks Rob, It was a port issue, I was able to mount the directory. I added the ingress rule on my server A and was able to mount the drive on server B as you said. I want to know, is it necessary to add egress rule also on my server A as it seems to be working fine without it.

Comment: I think in azure the default outbound rule (egress) is for all ports so you should be fine with the default